# Java - pass type to superclass static method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

Let's say I have simple class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public String field1 = "Field1";
    public String field2 = "Field2";
    public String field3 = "Field3";
}
```

I have multiple pojo classes in my project and I want to be able to serialize each object to json. So I created new `Serializer` class (gson used to serialize):

```
public class Serializer
{
    public String toJson()
    {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

And my example class extends `Serializer`:

```
public class TestClass extends  Serializer
{
    public String field1 = "Field1";
    public String field2 = "Field2";
    public String field3 = "Field3";
}
```

And I am able to serialize any object of class extending `Serializer` by calling `toJson` method, like this:

```
TestClass test1 = new TestClass();
String json =  test1.toJson();
```

Now I want construct class object by calling static method `fromJson`. So my `TestClass` looks like this:

```
public class TestClass extends  Serializer
{
    public String field1 = "Field1";
    public String field2 = "Field2";
    public String field3 = "Field3";

    public static TestClass fromJson(String json)
    {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<TestClass>() {}.getType());
    }
}
```

So, I can create new object by calling:

```
TestClass test2 = TestClass.fromJson(json);
```

Of course, this is not good approach, because I need to include `fromJson` implementation in my all classes.

Question: how to move `fromJson`to superclass (`Serializer`), and provide single, type dependent implementation for `fromJson` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define static `fromJson()` method in `Serializer` base class:

```
public static class Serializer {
    public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Type type) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```
TestClass obj = TestClass.fromJson(json, TestClass.class);
```

It's not perfect with redundant type information and doesn't support generics well. One should favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and in this case keep serialization out of the class hierarchy. This approach has no advantage over simply:

```
TestClass obj = new Gson().fromJson(json, TestClass.class);
```

Comment: The only advantage is gson call hidden

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I would not pass a `Class`, but a `Type` instead

Comment: Should you favor inheritance in this instance if there was some consistent Gson configuration, like setting prettyprint for example?

Comment: @TobySmith why not to have separate `FormatConverter` class? What is the use of keeping a `String` of JSON in Java program other than immediately displaying or storing it?

@Eugene thanks, updated.